# R: subsetting with respect to a vector

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, subset

I am trying to figure out how to apply a certain function only to the rows of a matrix with the same entry on the last column, but no luck until now.

My matrix (that we are going to call simply `matrix` and suppose it is 5x4) looks like this:

```
d1.1   d1.2   d1.3   NAME1 
d2.1   d2.2   d2.3   NAME1 
d3.1   d3.2   d3.3   NAME2 
d4.1   d4.2   d4.3   NAME3
d5.1   d5.2   d5.3   NAME2`
```

I want to perform the summary statistics `fun1` on the rows with the same name, in order to get a final matrix that looks like this:

```
fun1(d1.1, d2.1)   fun1(d1.2, d2.2)   fun1(d1.3, d2.3)   NAME1
fun1(d3.1, d5.1)   fun1(d3.2, d5.2)   fun1(d3.3, d5.3)   NAME2
d4.1               d4.2               d4.3               NAME3.
```

It is also fine if `fun1` is also performed on 'single' rows, i.e.

```
fun1(d1.1, d2.1)   fun1(d1.2, d2.2)   fun1(d1.3, d2.3)   NAME1
fun1(d3.1, d5.1)   fun1(d3.2, d5.2)   fun1(d3.3, d5.3)   NAME2
fun1(d4.1)         fun1(d4.2)         fun1(d4.3)         NAME3.
```

I tried with

`sapply(subset(matrix[,1:3], as.character(matrix[,4])==as.character(listofnames)),  fun1)`

but of course it does not work. The current problem is on the subsetting `as.character(matrix[,4])==as.character(listofnames)`, since the two objects have different dimensions, but I am sure this is not the only one.

I tried to look for similar problems but I just found subsetting by specified (numerical) conditions (>3) or by patterns (every group of 7 ordered entries). No luck with factors or characters.

I guess there may be something helpful in the `plyr` package, but I am not able to make it work. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

**Update**

In my case, `fun1=min`. The problem has changed meanwhile: while keeping the data grouped by `NAME`, I would like to get the min of, say, column 1 in each group and to save the whole row where the min is found, like this: suppose `d1.1 < d2.1` and `d5.1 < d3.1`, then the matrix

```
d1.1   d1.2   d1.3   NAME1 
d2.1   d2.2   d2.3   NAME1 
d3.1   d3.2   d3.3   NAME2 
d4.1   d4.2   d4.3   NAME3
d5.1   d5.2   d5.3   NAME2
```

should become

```
d1.1   d1.2   d1.3   NAME1 
d4.1   d4.2   d4.3   NAME3
d5.1   d5.2   d5.3   NAME2
```

without loss of the other columns.
I tried playing around with the `mutate` and `summarise` arguments as suggested, but keep getting warnings and errors (and actually I do not find the `help()` very helpful at all).

Comment: @jejroje It may be better to convert your `matrix` to `data.frame` if the columns are of different `classes`

Comment: I updated the post.  When you do `summarise_each` or `summarise`, the output will be 1 row for each grouping variable.  So, if you have comments in each row and want to keep it, one possibility after `summarise_each` is to use `left_join` with original dataset or just use `mutate_each`.  It is not exactly clear what your expected output would be.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
dfSelectSummary <- df %>% 
              group_by(name) %>% 
             summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE), sd=sd(., na.rm=TRUE),
             median=stats::median(., na.rm=TRUE)), starts_with("X"))

dfSelectSummary[,1:4]
#Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

#   name X1_mean  X2_mean  X3_mean
#1 NAME1   4.250 3.333333 4.888889
#2 NAME2   5.375 4.555556 6.000000
#3 NAME3   6.000 8.000000 9.000000
```

Or you could use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df, key='name')
nm1 <- colnames(DT[, as.list(summary(X1[!is.na(X1)])), by=name])[-1]
DTSummary <- DT[,  c(Var=list(nm1),
    lapply(.SD, function(x) summary(x[!is.na(x)]))), by=name]

head(DTSummary,8)
#    name     Var    X1    X2     X3    X4    X5
#1: NAME1    Min.  1.00 0.000  0.000 3.000  0.00
#2: NAME1 1st Qu.  2.00 2.000  1.000 3.750  3.25
#3: NAME1  Median  3.50 3.000  6.000 7.500  5.00
#4: NAME1    Mean  4.25 3.333  4.889 6.375  5.00
#5: NAME1 3rd Qu.  6.00 5.000  8.000 8.250  7.25
#6: NAME1    Max. 10.00 7.000 10.000 9.000 10.00
#7: NAME2    Min.  0.00 0.000  0.000 1.000  1.00
#8: NAME2 1st Qu.  3.75 4.000  4.000 3.000  4.25
```

Another option would be to try `summaryBy` from `doBy`

```
library(doBy)
 summaryBy(.~name, data=df,
    FUN=function(x) c(mean=mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), var= var(x, na.rm=TRUE),
                    median=median(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

If you have a `numeric` name column, you may not need to convert the `matrix`

```
 m1 <- as.matrix(cbind(name=as.numeric(df$name), df[,-1]))
 by(m1[,-1], m1[,1], FUN=summary)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(45)
df <- data.frame(name=sample(paste0("NAME", 1:3),20, replace=TRUE),
        matrix(sample(c(NA, 0:10), 20*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```

#### Update

If you need the results in the `long` form and would like to keep the `comments` column, you could use `mutate_each`

```
 df1 <- df %>% 
           group_by(name) %>% 
           mutate_each(funs(min=min(., na.rm=TRUE)), starts_with("X"))

 colnames(df1)[2:6] <- paste0("Min", colnames(df1)[2:6])
 head(df1,3)
 #Source: local data frame [3 x 7]
 #Groups: name

 #   name MinX1 MinX2 MinX3 MinX4 MinX5 Comments
 #1 NAME2     0     0     0     1     1     Fair
 #2 NAME1     1     0     0     3     0      Bad
 #3 NAME1     1     0     0     3     0     Good
```

#### newdata

```
  set.seed(45)
  df <- data.frame(name=sample(paste0("NAME", 1:3),20, replace=TRUE),
          matrix(sample(c(NA, 0:10), 20*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5), 
             Comments=sample(c("Good", "Fair", "Bad", "ugly"), 20, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. I was wondering, the `summarise_each` function can not "save" other variables in the output, can it? I have some comments next to each name, my summary statistics is _min_, so I was wondering if, besides the value and the name, I could get the comments corresponding to the appropriate value.

Comment: @jeiroje Are these comments unique to each row or they have repeats?

Comment: Thanks @akrun. The comments are both unique and repeated, but if I get the unique ones then I can mask them and get the repeated ones. I updated the question as well, since the problem has changed meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I think I made it!

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>%
       group_by(NAMES) %>%
       filter(df, X1 == min(X1))
```

Minimum returned, no data removed.
I found a similar answer on another thread. It would have the problem that it returns all rows if multiple minima are present, but this is not my case.